# Is there a method to remove item from ScrollView widget?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Or can I get access an item after adding it to `ScrollView` widget?

Example:

```
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView {...}
scrollView:insert(display.newImage("img1.png", 0, 0))
scrollView:insert(display.newImage("img2.png", 100, 0))
```

Next I want to remove 1st image from `scrollView`:

```
scrollView:remove(1) -- has no effect
```

**Update**: My solution:

```
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView {...}
scrollView.content = {}
scrollView.content[#scrollView.content+1]= display.newImage("img1.png", 0, 0)
scrollView:insert(scrollView.content[#scrollView.content])
scrollView.content[#scrollView.content+1]= display.newImage("img2.png", 0, 0)
scrollView:insert(scrollView.content[#scrollView.content])
...
-- at some point I want to delete some item
scrollView.content[n]:removeSelf()
table.remove(scrollView.content, n)
```

Comment: thanks, this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView {...}
local img_1 = display.newImage("img1.png", 0, 0)
local img_2 = display.newImage("img2.png", 100, 0)
scrollView:insert(img_1)
scrollView:insert(img_2)
```

Then:

```
img_1:removeSelf()
-- or
img_2:removeSelf()
```

Keep coding.................... :)

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answer above, you may also use:

```
display.remove( myImage )
```

This checks if the image is not nil before removing it.

Answer (score 1):

calling display.remove() or the object's:removeSelf() will remove the object from the display hirearchy.  If you want to keep the object around but not have it in your scrollView you can simply insert it into another display.newGroup() since display objects can only be in one display group at a time.  If your doing this in Storyboard, you could insert it into the storyboard's view group.  If you simply want to get rid of it, calling display.remove() or the object's :removeSelf() is what you want, just remember to nil out the reference to it.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
Object:removeSelf()
```

I have used it several times in my Android game phoenix tears when I needed to clear up memory and textures as well as hide objects.

Good luck!